# Tor client doesn't connect if relay's available bandwidth is less than x

Tags: relays, configuration, bandwidth, speed

Is there a way to config Tor client not to connect to relays which their usable bandwidth is less than 10Mbit/s ?

I don't mean the relays total available bandwidth. I mean usable bandwidth by client . for example a relay has 100Mbit/s available but is strict.